# Textjoin matching not working properly, returns error or blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the formula returning no values

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B1:B4=A1,A1:A4,""))
```

Ive entered it in array form and regular both return a blank or n/a, are the columns placement to blame? Help would be appreciated.

Example

```
1 1    
2 1    
3 6    
4 9
```

Result: 1,2

Comment: Works for me, are you sure you have TEXTJOIN and that you are correctly using Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: Yes as I am using Excel 2019, and the function syntax appears when entered in the formula bar. I'm entering different ranges but I don't get any results maybe I need to expand it somehow so that the formula works. I've tried multiple conditions where A1=B1:B4 and B1=A1:A4 to return but I get the same result.

Comment: When you array enter the formula does Excel put the `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Ok,I found the problem, this function will not return proper results if it has formula references or n/a #value or #ref error in the one of the ranges. How could I handle these error? The brackets were missing thanks for the tip.